# Derivative rules and trig identities for complex variables

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

It appears to me that all trig identities and derivative rules are of the same form for complex numbers as in real numbers. Are there any exceptions?

Comment: Short answer: no. They can all be derived from Euler's formula, or the power series representations. The inverse trigonometric functions will be more subtle because they are multivalued.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you mean by deriving derivative/trig identity from Euler's formula?

Comment: If you expand both sides of $e^{zw}=e^ze^w$ and work out the details for the real and imaginary parts and use the identies that express $\cos z$ and $\sin z$ in terms of complex exponentials you'll get the usual addition formulas for $\cos$ and $\sin$. You can do that here in an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following trigonometric identity holds for any real number $x$, $$|\cos x|^2+|\sin x|^2=1.$$
Is it true that  $|\cos z|^2+|\sin z|^2=1$ for all $z\in \mathbb{C}$?

Comment: No. But is is true without the absolute values. Those don't matter in the real case but do in the complex. I think inserting the absolute values makes it "not a trig identity" in the OP's terms.

Comment: @EthanBolker I see your point. I wait for OP's comment and if this is "not a trig identity" in the OP's terms I will delete my answer.

Comment: No, don’t delete it. I think it’s an interesting observation.